# Laravel 5 trigger route via javascript

Tags: laravel-5

on my projects show page, I have a button to create a document

```
<td id="tblButton"> {!! link_to_route('projects.document.create', 'Create Document', array($project->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) !!}</td>
```

This all works fine, I click on the button and I am linked to the route.

Now, I want to remove this button, and instead trigger the route via Javascript.  So I was thinking something like the following

```
$('#document').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'Project Identified') {
        $.ajax({
            url: ''
        })
    }
    else {

    }
});
```

But how can I give it the route projects.document.create and also pass it the project id?  I basically need to replicate what the button is doing within the ajax call.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `route` helper function. It'll just give you the URL rather than the full anchor markup.

```
$('#document').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'Project Identified') {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{!! route('projects.document.create', [$project->id]) !!}"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, says SyntaxError: missing } after property list.  It seems to produce the correct URL, maybe its because its not within quotation marks?

Comment: I'd imagine so, yeah. Give it a try inside quotes.

Comment: Hey, not using the route command.  At the moment I have hardcoded a url and that works fine.  I keep getting syntax errors when I try to add quotations etc

Comment: Can you update the question with the generated source so I can see what the output is?